# What impact have JS erros in performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

Does anyone if/how to many JS errors affect the server? Does it affect page render?

I have different errors in different sites (and I will fix them) but does it affect anything?

**Here is an example:**

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about server-side or client-side JS?

Comment: which browser, or JS interpreter are you showing there in the screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript errors most likely won't affect the server, since Javascript is executed on client side.
When it comes to page render, javascript errors might break your page. Let's get for example angular single application, if there is javascript error, you're most likely to see nothing at all.

Errors such as `undefined is not a function` might be sign for passing value instead of callback. For example:

```
$.ajax("url.php", 32); // the second parameter must be callback/function
```

You must review your code and fix them, because these errors are clear sign that something in your application is not working.

Comment: I see, even if it does not break does it affect load time?

Comment: Well if you wrap your code in try-catch there will be some performance impact, but at this point you should NOT be caring about performance caused by this errors - you should fix them.